# Cold Fusion Mail Being Repeatedly Sent By CF 10 Server

Tags: email, coldfusion, server, duplicates, cfmail

I'm migrating an app from a CF8 Server to a new CF 10 Server. As I was working with a form that sends an email everything seemed to work as it should and I received a copy of the email. And then another, and another. Every 15 seconds the server would send me the same email.

I took the mail server out of the CF Admin and still the duplicates kept coming. I checked the spool and undeliverable folders and they were both empty. The only thing that stops the emails from being sent is to stop the actual ColdFusion Application Service. When I restarted the service, however, the emails started up again!

I created a simple test page that has only a minimal CFMAIL tag with the basic fields and gave that a try. Same thing. Only now I have two emails coming into my inbox every 15 seconds while the service is running.

The mail log shows the emails being sent but doesn't give any indication of how they are being triggered. I can't understand where these emails might be stuck in the CF Server in a way that they are sent every 15 seconds. I've Googled it mightily with no leads.

Has anyone else experience anything like this? Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Obvious question, I suppose, but you never know. Is there any way the page or script in question is being accessed by someone other than you? A scheduled task or something? Any way at all it's being run after you load the page ONCE?

Comment: The http logs will help you follow @TRose's suggestion.

Comment: No other scripts are active, nor are there any other users. It's just me on the server. I actually just did a hard restart of the whole server and, when it came back up, the emails started being sent again with absolutely no interaction from me! It's crazy.

Comment: @E.Aborn That can't be right... Is there a loop or something on the page?  Any code or server settings you can disclose to us?

Comment: Believe me, @TRose, it's as crazy as it sounds. I've got someone from our corporate data center looking into it as well and they've never seen anything like this either. There are no loops on the page. In fact, I created a simple page with only basic html and a CFMAIL tag with only the required options to test and that email was added to the zombies that keep getting sent. We're perplexed to say the least. As for server settings, things are set up just like several of our other CF servers. If there's something in particular you're interested in, I will be glad to share.

Comment: Do you have "Spool mail messages for delivery" checked in the administrator?

Comment: Thank you for all of your suggestions. It turned out to be a two-pronged issue. The first is that the mail files in question were actually lodged in a sub-instance of ColdFusion which I overlooked. So prong one was my fault. The second part, why they kept being re-sent every 15 seconds, was a permissions issue. The resource account under which the CF app service is running didn't have permissions to the mail folder in the sub-instance. Once I added the resource account to the mail folder's permissions, the mail files were properly deleted after being sent instead of being stuck in the spool.